# Erro ao inserir dados no MYSQL com PYTHON

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysqli, python-2.7, syntax-error

Estou fazendo um trabalho na faculdade de uma fechadura eletronica e no momento estou criando um historico em um banco de dados MYSQL das tags lidas e a quem elas pertencem ou não. O problema no codigo é que ao executar ele não da erro algum, porem ele só contabiliza na coluna ID_evento (esta com auto incremento) e não apresenta informação alguma na tabela, fica invisivel as informações inseridas pelo python, mas ao executar a mesma query direto no SQL aparece normal e com o ID_evento respectivo a como se estivesse executado a query no python.

```
import string
import pymysql as sql

con = sql.connect(host='localhost',
                    user='root', 
                    password='root', 
                    db='rfid_teste',
                    charset='utf8mb4',
                    cursorclass=sql.cursors.DictCursor)
c = con.cursor()

query = 'SELECT NOME_USUARIO FROM rfid_teste WHERE TAG = "332b7b06"'
c.execute(query)
resultado = c.fetchone()
resultado_t = str(resultado)
sql_nome = resultado_t[18:25] #aqui sai o nome 'matheus'
sql_tag = 254145
query_i = "INSERT INTO registro (usuario, tag, data, hora) VALUES (%s, %s, CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_TIME() );"
c.execute(query_i, (sql_nome, sql_tag))
teste = (c.execute(query_i, (sql_nome, sql_tag)))
print (teste) #aqui retorna 1 não sei porque
```

Comment: Mesmo retirando as aspas duplas e colocando somente ' ' não roda.

Comment: a query deveria ficar assim `query = "SELECT NOME_USUARIO FROM rfid_teste WHERE TAG = '332b7b06'"`, isso não funciona?

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o erro, faltava um commit após a execução da query.
No meu caso ficou assim:

````
c.execute(query_i, (sql_nome, sql_tag))
con.commit()```


A partir daí inseriu o dado.
````

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).